The missing two letters
What are the two missing letters (indicated by __)
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PR0BLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM
PROBLEM

YM MD HP __


Are you sure there are 22 problems and not 23?

@sarsaparilla I had a formatting error. Should be correct now.

aw that edit spoils a bit, so don't click if you don't want to know

The missing letters are:

 JR

Explanation:
The word PROBLEM listed 23 times seems a clear reference to

 Hilbert's Problems, of which there are 23.

The three sets of letters at the bottom correspond to

 The four discoverers of Matiyasevich's theorem, also called the Matiyasevich–Robinson–Davis–Putnam or MRDP theorem in honor of these four:
 Yuri Matiyasevich (YM)
 Julia Robinson (JR)
 Martin Davis (MD)
 and Hilary Putnam (HP).
 This theorem resulted in the resolution to Hilbert's 10th problem, which is how it relates to the list of 23 problems. The problem has no (zero) solution, which is why the 10th "PROBLEM" contains a 0 instead of an O (credit @theozh - I didn't even notice the zero).
 So, the missing initials are JR!


so, that's why there is a 0 (zero) instead of O at the 10th problem...
